# Getter is deprecated after converting code to Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, getter

I'm trying to set some values to some dialog properties based on list item position and have just converted some code from Java to Kotlin, but for some reason, all the `myList[position]` instances within the click listener return this error:

> 'getter for position: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java.

However for `onBindViewHolder` What alternative can be used to resolve this error?

```
class MyRVAdapter(private val myList: ArrayList<Item>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRVAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.myBtn.text = (myList[position].textBtnTitle)
     }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.my_cv, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    class ViewHolder (itemView : View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val myBtn = itemView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_a)!!

        init {
            myBtn.setOnClickListener {
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(myBtn.context)
                builder.setTitle(myList[position].txtDialogTitle)
                builder.setMessage(myList[position].txtDialogMessage)
                builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok){ dialog, _ -> dialog.dismiss() }

                val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
                dialog.show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AdapterPosition?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce `myList` still remains in red as an `Unresolved reference`

Comment: The way you are going about it is wrong IMO, I wouldnt show a dialog in my viewholder class, create callbacks so that your activity can listen for them then pass the position of the view holder in the callback then get the item from your adapter in your activity. I think its because you are trying to use your list in your viewholder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the references to `position` inside your ViewHolder class.

Use `adapterPosition` there instead. The Java equivalent is `getAdapterPosition()`. If you were using `getPosition()` in Java, you may have had the deprecation warning suppressed.

Comment: `myList` still remains in red as an `Unresolved reference`

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question, but you need to add the `inner` modifier to the ViewHolder class.

Comment: It goes before `class`. I recommend reading the documentation for Kotlin.

Answer (score 8):

> This method is deprecated. This method is confusing when adapters nest other adapters. If you are calling this in the context of an Adapter, you probably want to call getBindingAdapterPosition() or if you want the position as RecyclerView sees it, you should call getAbsoluteAdapterPosition().

[Source:https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()]

Answer (score 2):

```
 itemSelectedForPreview(layoutPosition)
```

OR

```
itemSelectedForPreview(bindingAdapterPosition)
```

[image]